# Adding JQuery file in XML only if not yet added

Tags: xml, extensions, jquery

I am new to Magento Extension developer and i am creating an Image Slider. I am having problem on including JS file via XML file. How to check and include our JQuery file so that my extension run smoothly even if the JQuery.js already included by another extension.
Thank in Advance

Comment: Short answer: There is no way.

Comment: Is there any way or substitute to do this work ?

Comment: Don't know. I'm avoiding fronted

Comment: Can you give me some help about how are you avoiding this issue on frontend ?

Comment: No, I avoid developing frontend things, like JS and HTML. So I don't have these issues.

Comment: Hey i achieve this task by using ifconfig in XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can actually be achieved quite easily. First upload the jQuery library to your skin js directory.

Next in your `local.xml` add the following

```
<default>
   [...]
   <reference name="head">
      <block type="core/template" name="jquery.optional" template="path/to/jquery.phtml"/>
   </reference>
   [..]
</default>
```

and then the `path/to/jquery.phtml` file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (!!!jQuery)
   {
      script=document.createElement('script');
      script.type='text/javascript';
      script.src='<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery.js');?>';

      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
   }
</script>
```

I haven't tested this so might need a little tweaking but the logic behind it is that since Magento uses prototype which is mapped to `$` jQuery is always mapped to the `jQuery` variable. If it is undefined jQuery must not be loaded yet.

In that case we'll create a new script tag with the jQuery url as it's `src` and add it to the head.

Comment: Thanx @Sander. You give me new way to achieve this task.